# Rails : Removing empty values in a select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my select tag for a form:

```
<%= f.select(:example_name, ModelName.all.collect {|p| [ p.example_name, p.example_name ] }, {:include_blank => 'Select Example'}) %>
```

This returns all the example_name for the model ModelName. But the model has empty values stored in the database.

Thus, I want the select tag to retrieve only the valid entries leaving the empty or nil values.

How do we do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your query from

```
ModelName.all
```

to

```
ModelName.where("example_name <> ''")
```

This will omit **both** `NULL` and `""` values.

**Note** It's bad practice to put a query directly in the view; there's generally no need for it. That query should be used in an assignment in your controller action.

```
@select_options = ModelName.where(...
```

and then in your view

```
<%= f.select(:example_name, @select_options.collect { [...
```

You arguably should move even the `collect` into the action too.

Comment: The condition worked perfect. Thanks for explaining everything in details.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<%= f.select(:example_name, ModelName.where("example_name IS NOT NULL && example_name != ''").collect {|p| [ p.example_name, p.example_name ] }, {:include_blank => 'Select Example'}) %>
```